# Laravel Framework

Tags: laravel

I am trying to run my Laravel project and they give me the error shown in the screenshot:

[image: Laravel error]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please copy the text here, that will be readable and searchable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install composer on the project. Run `composer install` command on the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is running `composer install`, which will import your packages and create the vendor folder, along with the autoload script.

It is also possible to update a single package by naming it, for example:

```
composer update ramsey/uuid
```

If you already have installed then update the composer.

```
composer update
```

Just run this command first

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

A composer is a tool that automates downloading and installing PHP libraries. Composer helps you with dependency management, which is keeping track of all the code libraries your project depends on. A composer is a tool that will help you save a lot of time and frustration when it comes to setting up your project. It's a "must-have" for any web development project.
On the project, a composer must be installed. Run the `composer install` command from the project's root.